# Combine Token & Session authentication (Spring Security, REST API)

Tags: spring, rest, security, mobile, spring-security

I want, that my `REST API`, developed on `Spring`, can be used both by mobile and browser.

For **mobile** I used token based authentication in **Spring Config**:

```
  http
     .anonymous().and()
     .servletApi().and()
     .headers().cacheControl().and()
     .csrf().disable()
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
     .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
     .anyRequest().permitAll()
     .and()
     .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

For **browser** version I used session base authentication **Spring Config**:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/", false)
    .and()
    .logout().addLogoutHandler(new CookieClearingLogoutHandler())
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .logoutUrl("/logout")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll()
    .and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
    .maximumSessions(1)
```

Both configs works perfect separately.
**Question:**  How to combine 2 configs, that my REST API can be used by browser and mobile?